# Unity not opening plugin activity, package seems incorrect

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to use [this plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84876) to open an android image picker, however it errors when launched.

The calling script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using LukeWaffel.AndroidGallery;

public class LoadImageWithMagic : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image image;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OpenGallery() {
        Debug.Log ("It clicked");
        AndroidGallery.Instance.OpenGallery (GalleryCallback);
    }

    public void GalleryCallback() {
        image.material.mainTexture = AndroidGallery.Instance.GetTexture ();
        AndroidGallery.Instance.ResetOutput ();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
       <activity android:name= "com.lukewaffel.androidgallery.Gallery"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Error from logcat:

```
08-25 09:53:09.029 3458-3474/com.TNOAB.FindMyPet I/Unity: It clicked

                                                          (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
08-25 09:53:09.036 3458-3474/com.TNOAB.FindMyPet I/Unity: [Singleton] An instance of LukeWaffel.AndroidGallery.AndroidGallery is needed in the scene, so '(singleton) LukeWaffel.AndroidGallery.AndroidGallery (UnityEngine.GameObject)' was created with DontDestroyOnLoad.

                                                          (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
08-25 09:53:09.060 1485-1737/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.TNOAB.FindMyPet/com.lukewaffel.androidgallery.Gallery} from uid 10061 on display 0
08-25 09:53:09.082 3458-3474/com.TNOAB.FindMyPet I/Unity: AndroidJavaException: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.TNOAB.FindMyPet/com.lukewaffel.androidgallery.Gallery}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                          android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.TNOAB.FindMyPet/com.lukewaffel.androidgallery.Gallery}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
                                                              at com.lukewaffel.androidgallery.UnityBinder.OpenGallery(UnityBinder.java:12)
                                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                                            at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c
```

It appears that the issue is Unity is prepending my package to the package of the plugin, causing it to not be found. I have attempted to change my package to the package of the plugin and it still had the same error.

I have tried reinstalling the app and still cannot get the gallery to open.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the issue was all of the plugin files were placed into a subdirectory, so unity could not find the AndroidManifest.xml. After moving all of the items out of the subdirectory, the Gallery opened.

As a note to anyone copying the above code, I then discovered an unrelated error, `image.material.mainTexture = AndroidGallery.Instance.GetTexture ();` should be `image.sprite = AndroidGallery.Instance.GetSprite ();`